# Speeding up AES decryption in Node js

Tags: javascript, express, aes, node-crypto

I wanted to create web page on which would be displayed data, previously decrypted on server. On server in app.js all of data from one folder is read and then decrypted.

```
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var bytes = [];

var markers = fs.readdirSync("views/images");

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length ; ++i) {
bytes[i] = fs.readFileSync("views/images/" + 
markers[i]).toString('utf8');
};
```

Than data is decrypted and send to page

```
app.get('/index', function(req, res) {
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
try{
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length ; ++i) {
      bytes[i] = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(markers[i],Rf3hgf93).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);                       
       };
      res.render('index',{bytes:bytes});

      }catch (err){
         res.render('index',{bytes:''});
         console.log("error");
      };

  });
```

The thing is, it takes about 30 seconds to decrypt all of this files and send to client. There are about 35 decrypted txt files(each about 5mb). I know that node js is single-threaded and there is no concurrency. So, how can I speed up decrypting process ? Should I use Java/Python instead of node js, as far as I am concerned java is the most suitable language for this process because of multi-threading and concurrency.

Comment: if the files are the same and never change or change by adding new ones, then a caching mechanism can help. Then one can try to spawn another process to decrypt the files and communicate to the parent process eg via a file-lock mechanism My 2 cents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[crypto-js](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js) is a pure JavaScript AES implementation. It is meant to run in a browser as well as in NodeJs.

For a pure NodeJs application use the built-in [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) API, which is native and as such much faster.